# ActiveAdmin Sortable and Cancancan Ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, jquery-ui-sortable, cancancan

I am building a Rails application using **ActiveAdmin** and **ActiveAdmin Sortable** gem to change posts order.

I haven’t been able to figure out how to authorize this action in my Cancancan **ability.rb** file.
If I use `can :manage, Post` it works but I don’t want to give all permissions, only some.
Which action should be used in my Ability file to only allow ordering ?

Thanks for your help !

**My project**:

- Rails 4.2.7.1 / Ruby 2.3.0
- ActiveAdmin 1.0.0 pre4
- Cancancan 1.15.0
- ActiveAdmin Sortable
  (https://github.com/mvdstam/activeadmin-sortable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **ActiveAdmin Sortable** gem with a resource, an action

```
:sort
```

will be added to the controller for your **Post**. I think you can use

```
can(:sort, Post)
```

in the ability.rb file. You may have to conditionally hide/show the sortable handle column. I think you can do it this way in the index part:

```
index do
  sortable_handle_column if can?(:sort, Post)
end
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try it